# Select CIDR that is in range of IP

Tags: mysql, select, cidr

So I have an IP like 45.76.255.14, and I have a table with rows of CIDR stored as a single varchar, how would
I select CIDRs that are in the range of that IP address. For example 45.76.255.14/31

So in theory: select CIDR where in range of IP

Comment: It doesn't really make sense.. Ip is not a range. A cidr can be...

Comment: @Dekel, You're correct, an IP is not a range, but I'm asking to fetch CIDRs that are in range of the IP, aka includes the IP

Comment: In theory: `select * from cidrlist where @ip between startip(cidr) and endip(cidr)`. Practically, it will depend on how you stored your data. If you e.g. store ranges as varchars (`45.76.255.14/31`), it will be harder to do the comparison than if you store them as integers for start and end of a range. But since you didn't give us your data model, the theory should suffice. A hint for doing it practically: MySQL has a function to convert an ip string (without subnet) to int: `INET_ATON()`. Depending on your data, you might need to write functions like `startip()`/`endip()` to convert a range.

Comment: @Solarflare, I'm storing it in a single varchar column, would that be too difficult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing IP addresses in dotted quad notation in a `VARCHAR` is not the most optimal way of storing them, since dotted-quad is a human friendly representation of a 32 bit unsigned integer that doesn't lend itself to database indexing.  But sometimes it's fundamentally more convenient, and at small scale, the fact that queries require a table scan isn't usually a problem.

MySQL Stored Functions are a good way of encapsulating relatively complex logic behind a simple function that can be referenced in a query, potentially leading to easier-to-understand queries and reducing copy/paste errors.

So, here's a stored function I wrote called `find_ip4_in_cidr4()`.  It works somewhat similarly to the built-in function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) -- you give it a value and you give it a "set" (CIDR spec) and it returns a value to indicate whether the value is in the set.

First, an illustration of the function in action:

If the address is inside the block, return the prefix length.  Why return the prefix length?  Non-zero integers are "true," so we could just return `1`, but if you want to sort the matching results to find the shortest or longest of multiple matching prefixes, you can `ORDER BY` the return value of the function.

```
mysql> SELECT find_ip4_in_cidr4('203.0.113.123','203.0.113.0/24');
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| find_ip4_in_cidr4('203.0.113.123','203.0.113.0/24') |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  24 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT find_ip4_in_cidr4('192.168.100.1','192.168.0.0/16');
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| find_ip4_in_cidr4('192.168.100.1','192.168.0.0/16') |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  16 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Not in the block?  That returns 0 (false).

```
mysql> SELECT find_ip4_in_cidr4('192.168.100.1','203.0.113.0/24');
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| find_ip4_in_cidr4('192.168.100.1','203.0.113.0/24') |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT find_ip4_in_cidr4('192.168.100.1','192.168.0.0/24');
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| find_ip4_in_cidr4('192.168.100.1','192.168.0.0/24') |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There's a special case for the all-zeroes address, we return -1 (still "true", but preserves the sort order):

```
mysql> SELECT find_ip4_in_cidr4('192.168.100.1','0.0.0.0/0');
+------------------------------------------------+
| find_ip4_in_cidr4('192.168.100.1','0.0.0.0/0') |
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                             -1 |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Nonsense arguments return null:

```
mysql> SELECT find_ip4_in_cidr4('234.467.891.0','192.168.0.0/24');
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| find_ip4_in_cidr4('234.467.891.0','192.168.0.0/24') |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                NULL |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, teh codez:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `find_ip4_in_cidr4` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`mezzell`@`%` FUNCTION `find_ip4_in_cidr4`(
  _address VARCHAR(15), 
  _block VARCHAR(18)
) RETURNS TINYINT
DETERMINISTIC /* for a given input, this function always returns the same output */
CONTAINS SQL /* the function does not read from or write to tables */
BEGIN

-- given an IPv4 address and a cidr spec,
-- return -1 for a valid address inside 0.0.0.0/0
-- return prefix length if the address is within the block,
-- return 0 if the address is outside the block,
-- otherwise return null

DECLARE _ip_aton INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT INET_ATON(_address);
DECLARE _cidr_aton INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(_block,'/',1));
DECLARE _prefix TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT SUBSTRING_INDEX(_block,'/',-1);
DECLARE _bitmask INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT (0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - _prefix)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;

RETURN CASE /* the first match, not "best" match is used in a CASE expression */
  WHEN _ip_aton IS NULL OR _cidr_aton IS NULL OR /* sanity checks */
       _prefix  IS NULL OR _bitmask IS NULL OR
       _prefix NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 32 OR
       (_prefix = 0 AND _cidr_aton != 0) THEN NULL
  WHEN _cidr_aton = 0 AND _bitmask = 0 THEN -1
  WHEN _ip_aton & _bitmask = _cidr_aton & _bitmask THEN _prefix /* here's the only actual test needed */
  ELSE 0 END;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

An issue that is not specific to stored functions, but rather applies to most functions on most RDBMS platforms is that when a column is used as an argument to a function in `WHERE`, the server can't "look backwards" through the function to use an index to optimize the query.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not storing the IPs, I'm only storing the CIDR and matching the input with the database. This explains a lot.

Answer (score 2):

With the assist of this question: [MySQL query to convert CIDR into IP range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562416/mysql-query-to-convert-cidr-into-ip-range)

Here's the solution that works for me:

```
SELECT
    `cidr`
FROM
    cidr_list
WHERE
    INET_ATON('IP') BETWEEN(
        INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`cidr`, '/', 1)) & 0xffffffff ^(
            (
                0x1 <<(
                    32 - SUBSTRING_INDEX(`cidr`, '/', -1)
                )
            ) -1
        )
    ) AND(
        INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`cidr`, '/', 1)) |(
            (
                0x100000000 >> SUBSTRING_INDEX(`cidr`, '/', -1)
            ) -1
        )
    )
```

Comment: You don't really need a `BETWEEN` test, since all you really need to evaluate is whether network & mask == address & mask.  The mask itself provides the "between" by masking the insignificant bits.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, What do you propose I use instead?

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you're doing, I'm just saying you don't have to do the end range calculation, because that's the point of the netmask.  I use a stored function to encapsulate the logic.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I'm relatively new to CIDR and Netmasks, if you have a more optimized answer, I'll take it over mine.

Comment: It will probably be a few hours before I have an opportunity to do the subject justice -- if you have seen some of my answers, I try to make them pretty thorough -- but I'll be happy to post what I have.  I believe I may have a `find_ip4_in_cidr4()` funtion that is logically similar to the built-in `FIND_IN_SET()` function, but for matching address ranges.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, that's fine, I'll  just wait cause I have no idea what those functions do

Comment: I want to reiterate, I'm not saying there's anything wrong with your answer, only that it can be implemented in a way that's a little easier on the eyes and potentially less error-prone.  Hopefully you'll find my answer useful, as well.