# Comparing IPv4 IP address with Network address stored on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-modules, ip-address

I have a large table containing 3 Million network addresses and their location info

basic fields:

```
network: eg. 74.142.124.116/30,

latitude: eg. 40475, 

longitude: eg. 37.7548
```

The system also captures the ipv4 address of the user accessing the service (say, `216.255.211.106`).

I want to compare this ipv4 and network address and locate the ip address.. Is there a way of doing this in MySQL or node.JS?

Comment: Interesting combo of http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges and http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following method:

- Store the network as startIP and endIP (network & broadcast) in two separate columns in MySQL
- Find the record containing the address using a simple range query (`ip >= startIP and ip <= endIP`)

Implementation details:

The optimal datatype for IPv4 address in MySQL is `INT UNSIGNED`. You can convert your existing data by calculating network and broadcast addresses as (using your example data):

```sql
update mytable set startIP = inet_aton('74.142.124.116'), endIP = inet_aton('74.142.124.119')
```

Assuming your original parameter value (sourceIP) is a dotted decimal formatted IP addres as a string (i.e. '216.255.211.106') you can query the table (you need to add index on (startIP, endIP) as:

```sql
select lat, long from mytable where inet_aton(@sourceIP) >= startIP and inet_aton(@sourceIP) <= endIP
```

(@sourceIP is the parameter value)

Depending on the quality of your data, you might get multiple results (i.e. overlapping network ranges in your dataset)

**Update**

*Credits to Bernd Buffen's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562416/mysql-query-to-convert-cidr-into-ip-range)*

You can use the following statement to populate the two new columns:

```sql
update mytable set
startIP = INET_ATON( SUBSTRING_INDEX(cidr, '/', 1)) 
   & 0xffffffff ^ ((0x1 << ( 32 - SUBSTRING_INDEX(cidr, '/', -1))  ) -1 ) 
, endIP = INET_ATON( SUBSTRING_INDEX(cidr, '/', 1)) 
   | ((0x100000000 >> SUBSTRING_INDEX(cidr, '/', -1) ) -1 )
```

Assuming the original table has a `cidr` column.

Comment: How did you calculate the endIP value to "74.142.124.120"? I have 3 Million rows of Network addresses like this. What do I do for all the others?

Comment: I will add sample code to calculate network/broadcast address from CIDR

Comment: Added sample and also corrected my (now obvious) mistake: in your example, the broadcast address is 74.142.124.119

Comment: in the statement ```select lat, long from mytable where sourceIP >= startIP and sourceIP <= endIP``` what is the datatype of the sourceIP? Is it a string? Is it supposed to be like ```select lat, long from mytable where  "216.255.211.106" >= startIP and  "216.255.211.106" <= endIP```? I seem to get the wrong results for any IP that I give. Which also gives me a warning ```Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value```

Comment: I forgot to mention it: Assuming that the original parameter value is a string containing the sourceIP, you will have to convert it to an unsigned integer. This can be easily done with mysql's `inet_aton('<ip in dotted notation>')`. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: there are also two additional ```INET_NTOA```s  in  the population of new columns. After I removed it, and also added ```inet_aton('<ip in dotted notation>')``` everything was fine. Consider editing your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210650/discussion-between-cascader-and-clutch-prince).