# Which type has INET6_ATON? / Max length of INET6_ATON?

Tags: mysql, ip-address

I wanted to know how to save an `INET6_ATON` result to MYSQL. So I've read the MYSQL-Help article and it says, I should use `VARBINARY(16)`. But now, with an `IPv4`-Address it has the content `0x7F000001` and I'm unable to get results using SQL. My idea was to use `CHAR`, but in this case I don't know what's the maximum length of an `INET6_ATON`-result.

**So**: How to get MYSQL-results if the result is saved as `VARBINARY`?
**Or otherwise**: What's the maximum length of an `INET6_ATON`-result?

I'm converting the IP-Addresses using this SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT HEX(INET6_ATON("FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329"))
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Those are 16 bytes .... XX is 1 byte

Comment: @Drew Means I should use `CHAR(32)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the human readable column below is for human consumption.

The `inet6` column will contain out-of-range numbers should I say to make much sense to humans. Goobly goop, if you will.

```
create table myFriends
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    friendlyName varchar(100) not null,
    inet6 binary(16) not null,
    humanReadable char(32) not null
);

insert myFriends (friendlyName,inet6,humanReadable) values 
('Kathy Higgins',INET6_ATON("FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329"),HEX(INET6_ATON("FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329")));

select * from myFriends;
+----+---------------+------------------+----------------------------------+
| id | friendlyName  | inet6            | humanReadable                    |
+----+---------------+------------------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | Kathy Higgins | ■Ç      ☻☻│ ■▲â) | FE800000000000000202B3FFFE1E8329 |
+----+---------------+------------------+----------------------------------+
```

`FE80` represents 2 bytes. FE 80. Hexadecimal. Each byte ranges from 00 to FF (255).

Check out my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32020220) on different formats. Often nearly duplicate info is used in one table.

Comment: What is more efficient for MYSQL?

Comment: More efficient is the varbinary(16) as that is what a decent join would be on. Thinner is better. It depends in what context you use it for functions as it relates to usefulness to you.

Comment: What about IPv4? For example, `SELECT * FROM myFriends WHERE ipv4 = 0x7F000001` doesn't work.

Comment: Check out the edit at the bottom of my answer. Play with it for a while.

Comment: I changed the answer to `binary(16)`. Determine which is more appropriate for *your* setup and usage depending on padding. There is overhead for var this and that. If it is always generating 16 bytes, go with `binary(16)` and not `varbinary(16)`