# Auto-populate table with IP's depending on CIDR netmask

Tags: mysql, linux, ip, cidr

I have 2 tables `cidr` and `ip`.

In the first one I store CIDR netmask's. (2 column table, id_cidr, cidr), here is an example (the values are fictional):

```
 id_cidr |     cidr
---------+----------------
    1    | 14.44.182.0/24
---------+----------------
    2    | 26.232.49.0/22
```

In the second one I want to store the ip's within each cidr netmask (3 column table, id_ip, cidr_id, ip), here is an example (the values are fictional):

```
  id_ip  | cidr_id  |     ip
---------+--------------------------
    1    |    1     | 14.44.182.0
---------+--------------------------
    2    |    1     | 14.44.182.1
---------+--------------------------
    3    |    1     | 14.44.182.2
---------+--------------------------
   ...   |    1     | ...
---------+--------------------------
   256   |    1     | 14.44.182.255
---------+--------------------------
   257   |    2     | 26.232.48.0
---------+--------------------------
   258   |    2     | 26.232.48.1
---------+--------------------------
   259   |    2     | 26.232.48.2
---------+--------------------------
   ...   |    2     | ...
---------+--------------------------
  1280   |    2     | 26.232.51.255
```

What I want to achieve is the following: whenever I addd a cidr netmask into the `cidr table` I want my `ip table` to auto-populate the fields with all the range of ip's within that cidr netmask. Is there any way to achieve this in mysql?

Note: To convert a cidr netmask to a range of ip's click [here](http://magic-cookie.co.uk/iplist.html)

Comment: The first ip address generated under this `ip series = 26.232.49.0/22` is `26.232.48.0`. is it expected? And also tell us do you prefer calling a procedure to populate the second table?

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake, I corrected that. Yes I guess some procedure or any other solution besides PHP. So from mysql and I ask this because I am not experienced with advanced mysql.

Comment: What you want sounds like you want trigger for that. But calling procedure inside a trigger is discouraged. But if I were you then I would do it this way : 1) Insert into `cidr` table 2) get the last insert id 3) call the procedure providing the last inserted cidr id and the `cidr` itself in order to insert into the `ip` table

Comment: Is this of use to you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32020220) of mine, in particular the table with 1 row showing [this](http://i.imgur.com/uPXdfRo.jpg) ... less housekeeping

Answer (score 0):

**Procedure:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE populateIpProcedure(cidrID INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE my_cidr_id INT;
  DECLARE my_cidr_str VARCHAR(25);
  DECLARE my_initial_ip VARCHAR(15);
  DECLARE my_initial_ip_int INT;
  DECLARE my_ip_limit INT;
  DECLARE my_loop_variable INT DEFAULT 0;

  SET my_cidr_id = cidrID;
  SELECT cidr INTO my_cidr_str FROM cidr WHERE id_cidr = my_cidr_id;  
  SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_cidr_str,'/',1),SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_cidr_str,'/',-1)+0 INTO my_initial_ip, my_ip_limit;

  SET my_ip_limit = (SELECT POWER(2, (32-my_ip_limit)));
  SELECT INET_ATON(my_initial_ip) INTO my_initial_ip_int;


    WHILE my_loop_variable < my_ip_limit DO 
        INSERT INTO ip(cidr_id,ip) SELECT my_cidr_id, INET_NTOA(my_initial_ip_int+my_loop_variable);
    SET my_loop_variable := my_loop_variable + 1;
  END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The procedure above takes a `cidr` id as an argument.

Then it retrieves the record from `cidr` table by the given id.

Later it inserts all the ips under this cidr into to the `ip` table.

**Test:**

```
CALL populateProcedure(1);
```

This will insert 256 entries in `ip` table under this ip series `14.44.182.0/24`

**Test Schema & Data:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cidr`;
CREATE TABLE `cidr` (
  `id_cidr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cidr` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_cidr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `cidr` VALUES ('1', '14.44.182.0/24');
INSERT INTO `cidr` VALUES ('2', '26.232.49.0/22');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ip`;
CREATE TABLE `ip` (
  `id_ip` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cidr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` char(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ip`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```